# how to enable instants payout in stripe connect?

Tags: typescript, express, payment

I'm trying to add payout method in stripe connect with node js typescript

this is the route where I add payout method, the authMiddleware is to check if the user is connected and take his id and find the user and his account:

```
    router.post("/add-payout-method", authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.body.userId });
    if (user) {
      const  accountId  = user.accountId;
      const { accountType, accountDetails} = req.body;
      const account_holder_name=`${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`

      // Create a bank account or debit card token
      let externalAccountToken;
      if (accountType === "bank") {
        externalAccountToken = await stripe.tokens.create({
          bank_account: {
            country: "CA",
            currency: "CAD",
            account_holder_name: account_holder_name,
            account_holder_type: "individual",
            routing_number: accountDetails.routingNumber,
            account_number: accountDetails.accountNumber,
          },
        });
      } else if (accountType === "card") {
        externalAccountToken = await stripe.tokens.create({
          card: {
            number: accountDetails.cardNumber,
            exp_month: accountDetails.expMonth,
            exp_year: accountDetails.expYear,
            cvc: accountDetails.cvc,
            currency:"CAD"
          },
        });

         const externalAccount = await stripe.accounts.createExternalAccount(
           accountId,
           {
             external_account: externalAccountToken.id,
           }
         );

        await stripe.accounts.update(accountId, {
          capabilities: {
            transfers: { requested: true },
          },
        });
      } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid account type" });
      }

      // Associate the bank account or debit card with the Stripe account
      await stripe.accounts.createExternalAccount(accountId, {
        external_account: externalAccountToken.id,
      });

      res
        .status(200)
        .json({ success: true, message: "Payout method added successfully" });
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error adding payout method:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
  }
});
```

when I test it with postman it tells me that Instant Payouts are not enabled for this account.